# What does the control character X'0001' mean in IBM document

Tags: c#, symbols

I'm working with this [EHLLAPI Windows Status function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQ5Y_6.0.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/emulator_programming08.htm#func104) and have to implement this in C#.

The document said in the seventh and eighth byte (2 bytes = 16 bits) of the data should be set to `X'0001'` if I want to change the window's size.

> A 16- or 32-bit word containing the status set bits if the request
>   option is 1 (set status). The following codes are valid return values
>   if the request option is set status: X'0001' Change the window size.
>   (Not valid with minimize, maximize, restore, or move.)

I thought that `X'0001'` is the hexa number but it isn't. 
In the same document it has alot of that kind of symbol `X'01'` `X'0040'` ... and I don't know what it mean and how to implement it in C#.

Comment: _I thought that X'0001' is the hexa number but it isn't._ What makes you think so? Just because no digit above '8' is used? IBM has a long tradition some special rules..

Comment: Yes, and I think it relate to double byte characters, somehow

Comment: It is plain hex for a 16-bit ushort value.  Quoting: "The buffer size can be from 1 byte to 64 KB minus 256 bytes (X'FF00' bytes) in length".  Do swap E and H in this api name.

Answer (score 0):

It is 16bit number, which can be convert to 2 bytes

```
short a = 0x0040;
firstByte = BitConvert.GetByte(a)[0];
secondByte = BitConvert.GetByte(a)[1];
```